# Remove first char only if there are more than 2 same chars

Tags: php

I wanna remove colon (:) if it is exist in sentence. 
But if there are two or more colons on sentence, I just wanna remove first colon.

For example :

1. Panitera: NounAgent
2. :: Colon

If I remove colon, the first sentence muct become :  Panitera NounAgent.

But for the second sentence, it must become -> : Colon

here's the code :

```
function removeColon($string){
    $count = substr_count($string, ':');
    if ($count == 1){
    $string = str_replace(':', '', $string); 
    }
    if ($count > 1){
    // what to do 
    }
}
```

thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should approach this problem differently. First of all, you don't care how many instances of `:` there are in the string -- you just want to replace the first one.

So find the first one (if any) with [`strpos`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and then use [`substr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to "remove" that character from the string by getting the parts of the string that precede and follow it:

```
$pos = strpos($string, ':');
if ($pos === false) {
    return $string; // nothing to do
}

return substr($string, 0, $pos).substr($string, $pos + 1);
```

Be mindful of how to correctly check the return value of `strpos` to determine if `:` was found in the string -- there's a big warning in the documentation page because doing this incorrectly is easy and will result in bugs.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `limit` argument with 1 in [*preg_replace*](https://www.php.net//manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to just replace first occurence in the string,

```
echo preg_replace('/:/', '', $str, 1);
```

*[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/69P39QQ6)*.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with [preg_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), it has a `limit` parameter:

> limit
>       The maximum possible replacements for each pattern in each subject string. Defaults to -1 (no limit).

Answer (score 0):

Using a regular expression, you can do what you like (for adjacent colons). This function works for multiple `:` at different positions in the same string.

```
function remove_first_colons($str) {
    return preg_replace('/:(:*)/', '$1', $str);
}

echo remove_first_colons('Name::: Princess');     // Name:: Princess
echo remove_first_colons('Hello: World');         // Hello World
echo remove_first_colons('A: B C::D E:::F');      // A B C:D E::F
echo remove_first_colons('Panitera: NounAgent');  // Panitera NounAgent
echo remove_first_colons(':: Colon');             // : Colon
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
preg_replace('/^:{2,}/',':',$str);
```